# Pop_OS Upgrade Causes Stuff to Break

Tags: linux, vmware, gnome, xserver

**Alright, just a disclaimer:** I've been using some version of Unix or Linux for 30 years, I have good working knowledge, but when it comes to administration I'm enthusiastically dangerous :)

Every time I do the automated OS upgrade in Pop!_OS something bad happens. And I am not talking about apt update / apt dist-upgrade. I do mean going into the settings GUI and in the last item on the list clicking "Upgrade".

Last machine I did it on failed and I couldn't recover the system, not even from a bootable stick. That machine was on it's last leg, I just let it go and built a new box, it was time. Well here we are again, time for an upgrade to 20.10.

- I hit "upgrade os" (maybe it's "update os" I don't remember exactly
- It did some stuff, and said it needed to restart - Okay so now we're windows? Not thrilled
- Restart and end up at a gray screen where it sat at 0% progress bar for the update
- I let it sit a good long while, maybe 45 minutes, I was worried this mid-low range machine was just taking a while, nothing
- Cringe.. hit the reset button, the system rebooted and did "something" and then came up seemingly okay

Now here's the problem list:

1. Did the upgrade happen fully, completely, and successfully? How can I tell? This feels like I'm running windows and just rolling in the blind mystery..
2. VMWare Workstation wont launch. Nothing happens with icon click, from command line I get this error:

`/usr/bin/vmware: line 105: 159580 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) "$BINDIR"/vmware-modconfig --appname="VMware Workstation" --icon="vmware-workstation"`

Searching online a bunch there was a lot of talk that there may be permission problems after upgrade and running it as root would help. This did not work. I read that upgrading to VMWare 16.x will help. I'm open to it, but on principle WHY does this have to be the case?

3. I use another app that is installed from source, it's called MakeMKV. I've had no trouble with it until the Pop upgrade. Again, it doesn't launch from the icon. I rebuilt and reinstalled it. No go. Launching from command line returns:

`/snap/makemkv/217/bin/desktop-launch: line 51: /home/ritchie/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied`

`qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :1`

`Could not connect to any X display.`

Launching from the command line with **sudo** worked though! So wtf?

This feels like a key piece of the puzzle, that bit about not being able to connect to the display.

Since this post is so long I wont list the hardware, but am happy to if it helps diagnose.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

got the same with other snap packages...

tried to figure out what's wrong...
looks like some ENV variable is not set properly causing the error:

```sh
.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
```

but simply reinstalling the package resolves the issue:

```sh
sudo snap remove %package%
sudo snap install %package%
```